# YAML : Use mapped list vs array

Tags: data-structures, configuration, yaml, configuration-files

I am creating a configuration file for my application. To do it, I decided to use YAML for its simplicity and reliability.

I am currently designing a special part of my application: In this part, I have to list and configure all datasets I want to use in a module. To do that I wrote this :

```
    // Other stuff       
    datasets:
        rate_variation:
            name: Rate variation over time # Optional
            description: Description here # Optional
            type: POINTS_2D
            options:
                REFRESH_TIME: 5 # Time of refresh in second
        frequency_variation:
            name: Frequency variation over time
            description: Description here # Optional
            type: POINTS_2D
```

But, after some reflection, I have some doubts about it. Because maybe something like this is better :

```
    datasets:
        -   id: rate_variation
            name: Rate variation over time # Optional
            description: Description here # Optional
            type: POINTS_2D
            options:
                REFRESH_TIME: 5 # Time of refresh in second
        -   id: frequency_variation
            name: Frequency variation over time
            description: Description here # Optional
            type: POINTS_2D
```

I use the ID to identify each dataset in my scripts (two datasets must have a different id) and generate output files for each of them.
But now, I really don't know what is the best solution...

What would you recommend to use? And for what reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the first option, YAML enforces that there are no duplicate IDs. Therefore, an editor supporting YAML may support your user by showing an error in this case. With the second option, you need to check uniqueness in your code and the user only sees the error when loading the syntactically correct YAML into your application.

However, there are other factors to consider. For example, you may have a preference for the resulting in-memory data structures. If you use standard YAML implementations that deserialize to native data structures (PyYAML, SnakeYAML etc), the YAML structure imposes the type of the in-memory data structure (you can customize by writing custom constructors, but that's not trivial). For example, if you want to ask a dataset object for its ID, that is only directly doable with the second structure – if you use the first structure, you would need to search the parent table for the dataset value you have to get its ID.

So, final answer is (as always): It depends. Think about what you want to do with it. For simple configuration files, my second argument may be weaker than my first one, but I don't know what exactly you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 7):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- YAML can be normalized quite cleanly and in a straightforward manner using YAML `ddconfig` format
- Using this approach can simplify construction and maintenance of configuration files, and make them highly flexible for later use by many types of consuming applications.

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- Data normalization (aka YAML schema definition) with YAML `ddconfig` format

  - (tag:dreftymac@dreftymac.org,2017:`ddconfig`)
  - dmid://uu773yamldata1620421509

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** Developer graille_stentiplub is creating a configuration file format for use with YAML.

  - the data structure (i.e., schema) for the YAML must be flexible for use in many contexts.
  - the schema should be amenable to arbitrary and flexible queries where the structure of the YAML does not "get in the way".
  - the schema should be easy to read and understand by humans.
  - the schema should be easily manipulated by any programming environment capable of processing standard YAML.
- **Special considerations:** graille_stentiplub wants an easy way to determine when to use lists vs mappings.

#### Example

- the following is a simple config file using YAML `ddconfig` format

  ```
    dataroot:

        file_metadata_str: |
          ### <beg-block>
          ### - caption: "my first project"
          ###   notes:  |
          ###     * href="//home/sm/docs/workup/my_first_project.txt"
          ### <end-block>

        project_info:
          prj_name_nice:        StackOverflow Demo Answer Project
          prj_name_mach:        stackoverflow_demo_001a
          prj_sponsor_url:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349286
          prj_dept_url:         https://demo-university.edu/dept/basketweaving

        dataset_recipient_list:
          - graille_stentiplub@example.org
          - dreftymac_lufcrom@demo-university.edu
          - nobody_knows_who_you_are@example.com

        dataset_variations_table:
            -   dvar_id:            rate_variation
                dvar_name:          Rate variation over time      # Optional
                dvar_description:   Description here              # Optional
                dvar_type:          POINTS_2D
                dvar_opt_refresh_per_second: 5                    # Time in seconds

            -   dvar_id:            frequency_variation
                dvar_name:          Frequency variation over time
                dvar_description:   Description here              # Optional
                dvar_type:          POINTS_2D
  ```

#### Explanation

- The entire data structure is nested under a toplevel key called `dataroot` (this is optional).

  - Inclusion of the `dataroot` key makes the YAML structure more addressible but is not necessary.
  - Using a filesystem analogy, you can think of `dataroot` as a root-level directory.
  - Using an XML analogy, you can think of this as the root-level XML tag.
- The entire data structure consists of a YAML mapping (aka dictionay) (aka associative-array).

  - every mapping key is a first-level child of `dataroot` (or else a toplevel key if dataroot is omitted).
- There are different types of mapping keys:

  - **String**: (suffix `_str`) indicates that the mapped value is a string (aka scalar) value.
  - **List**: (suffix `_list`) indicates the mapped value is a list (aka sequence).
  - **Info**: (suffix `_info`) indicates the mapped value is mapping (aka dictionary) (aka associative-array).
  - **Table**: (suffix `_table`) indicates the mapped value is a sequence-of-mappings (aka table).
  - **Tree**: (suffix `_tree` or `_struct`) indicates a composite structure with support for one or more nested parent-child relationships.

#### Rationale

- The YAML `ddconfig` format coincides nicely with many different contexts and tools.
- This allows for simplified decision making when laying out the configuration file format, as well as simplified programming when parsing the file.

##### Simplicity

- a `_list` mapping consists of a sequence of scalar-value items with no nesting.
- a `_info` mapping consists of a scalar-key and a scalar-value (name-value pairs) with no nesting.
- a `_table` mapping is simply a sequence of `_info` mappings.
- nesting of arbitrary depth can be accomplished through YAML anchors and aliases, thus supporting the `_tree` composite data structure.

##### Similarity to relational databases

- You can think of a `ddconfig` `_info` mapping as a single record from a standard table in a relational database.
- You can think of a `ddconfig` `_table` mapping as a standard table in a relational database.
- This similarity makes it extremely straightforward to transmit YAML to a database if and where necessary.

##### Anchors and aliases

- The YAML `ddconfig` format works well with YAML anchors and aliases.
- One or more `_info` mappings can be easily converted to a `_table` mapping by way of aliases.
- Multiple `_info` mappings can be combined together into another `_info` mapping by way of YAML merge keys.

#### See also

- github link https://github.com/dreftymac/trypublic/search?q=uu773yamldata1620421509